# Rotating a skewed element for a mirror effect not working

Tags: css, rotation, transform

I am attempting to create the general shape of the skewed element in the image below. It seems whatever I do that I cannot get the same skewed effect.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

[image]

```css
#twrap {
 height: 50vh;
 width: 100%;
}
.leftSide, .rightSide {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 width: 50%;
 height: 100%;
}
.leftSide {
 background: black;
 position: relative;
}
#slant:before {
 height: 100%;
 width: 30%;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    background: inherit;
 background: green;
    position: absolute;
    top: -6px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
 top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transform: skewY(60deg) rotate(360deg) scaleX(-1);
    -moz-transform: skewY(60deg) rotate(360deg) scaleX(-1);
    -ms-transform: skewY(60deg) rotate(360deg) scaleX(-1);
    -o-transform: skewY(60deg) rotate(360deg) scaleX(-1);
    transform: skewY(60deg) rotate(360deg) scaleX(-1);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 100%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 100%;
    -o-transform-origin: 100%;
    transform-origin: 100%;
}
.rightSide {
 background: purple;
}
```

```html
<div id="twrap">
 <div class="leftSide">
  <div id="slant"></div>
 </div><div class="rightSide">
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

skew should be -60...

```css
#twrap {
 height: 50vh;
 width: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.leftSide, .rightSide {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 width: 50%;
 height: 100%;
}
.leftSide {
 background: black;
 position: relative;
}
#slant:before {
 height: 100%;
 width: 50%;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    background: inherit;
 background: purple;
    position: absolute;
    top: -6px;
    right:0;
    bottom: 10px;
 top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transform: skewY(-60deg) rotate(180deg) scaleX(-1) scaleY(1);
    -moz-transform: skewY(-60deg) rotate(180deg) scaleX(-1) scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: skewY(-60deg) rotate(180deg) scaleX(-1) scaleY(1);
    -o-transform: skewY(-60deg) rotate(180deg) scaleX(-1) scaleY(1);
    transform: skewY(-60deg) rotate(180deg) scaleX(-1) scaleY(1);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 100%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 100%;
    -o-transform-origin: 100%;
    transform-origin: 100%;
}
.rightSide {
 background: purple;
}
```

```html
<div id="twrap">
 <div class="leftSide">
  <div id="slant"></div>
 </div><div class="rightSide">
 </div>
</div>
```